# YouTube Api Sending POST Request

Tags: ios, http, post, youtube, youtube-api

When I send a POST Request to the YouTube Api it gives me something like this back:

```
<errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'><error><domain>GData</domain>>
<code>ParseException</code><internalReason>Element type "entry" must be followed 
by either         
attribute specifications, "&gt;" or "/&gt;".</internalReason></error></errors>
```

I don't know what it means.

Comment: <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><entry xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\"xmlns:yt=\"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007\"><content>Comment</content></entry>

Comment: I try to post a comment under a video

Comment: It may be choking on the xmlns attribute in the <entry> tag.  Does it belong there?  And are you missing the <feed> tag?

Comment: Yes, at least the api says so:POST /feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID/ratings
Host: gdata.youtube.com
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
Content-Length: CONTENT_LENGTH
Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
GData-Version: 2
X-GData-Key: key=DEVELOPER_KEY

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
       xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
  <gd:rating value="4" min="1" max="5"/>
</entry>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what is in your comment is exactly what you posted, you've got a typo -- the second xmlns attribute needs a space between the preceding quote mark and the attribute name so that it's recognized as a valid attribute -- this is likely what is triggering the parsing error.